# Ubuntu Server Wifi connection fails after each sudo apt upgrade

Tags: networking, wireless, upgrade

I have an issue with my Ubuntu 18.04.3 server. The server connects to my home network via wifi and has a static IP address. It works perfectly most of the time but I repeatedly experience the following:

1. I ssh into the machine and find there are a number of upgrades available
2. I install the upgrades
3. I reboot
4. I can no longer reach the machine by ssh
5. I go to the machine and log in. No IP address is displayed on the welcome screen
6. I reboot. All is well again.

I have gone through the logs for a successful and unsuccessful boot (success in terms of making a connection). The logs are broadly similar but I find a successful boot ends with:

```
wpa_supplicant[760]: wlp1s0: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 40:0d:10:ad:70:2f [GTK=TKIP]
```

An unsuccessful boot appears to briefly establish a connection but then has:

```
wpa_supplicant[763]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlp1s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
systemd[1]: Stopping WPA supplicant for netplan wlp1s0...
etc...
```

There is no explicit error, just messages about ending the connection. Does anyone have any ideas about why this might happen? Would it be possible to have a script run shortly after a reboot to see if a connection has been established and if not try to get one?

Edit 20191222:

Since first asking this question I now have two cron jobs that run early on a Sunday morning. The first performs updates and reboots. The second, an hour later, simply reboots again. This seems to keep the server online at times when I use it. After checking the logs the server appears to sometimes be online after the first reboot and always online after the second.

Output of: **cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

50-cloud-init.yaml

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

wificonfig.yaml

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.0.66/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      access-points:
        "99PinkGins":
          password: "###############"
      optional: true
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.66/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8]
      optional: true
```

Output of **cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

Output of **sudo lshw -C network**

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 8260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 3a
       serial: 00:bb:60:41:7a:8a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-72-generic firmware=34.0.1 ip=192.168.0.66 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:28 memory:fbefe000-fbefffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 06
       serial: 1c:6f:65:28:8d:14
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:ee00(size=256) memory:fbbff000-fbbfffff memory:fbbf8000-fbbfbfff
```

Comment: Anyway, your .yaml files are messed up. You've got two overlapping .yaml files, two similar static IP addresses assigned to two network interfaces, and "optional: true" on the wireless interface.

Comment: status please...

Comment: There have been no updates to apply since I made the changes to the yaml file so I don’t know if this has solved the issue. The problem arises on about 75% of updates so I’d like to see two updates work without issue before accepting the answer. I think this is reasonable and to accept it any earlier could mislead others. Thanks for your help, it is appreciated

Comment: status please...

Comment: There have been no updates to apply since I made the changes to the yaml file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have only ONE .yaml file in /etc/netplan. It should look like something similar to this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.66/24] # don't use the same IP address as enp3s0
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "99PinkGins":
          password: "###############"
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: One subsequent question about nameservers: why use “addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]“ rather than “addresses: [192.168.0.1,8.8.8.8] which is shown as the example for WiFi on Netplan.io? Would the former be more appropriate outside a home network?

Comment: @PonJar Use the `systemd-resolve --status` command to view your current active servers. Try it with and without 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. You'll probably find that 192.168.0.1 gets the first request, as the router caches dns records.

Comment: I just want to thank you again for your help with this question. The solution I have adopted is to follow your suggestion to remove “optional: true” from the wifis section. This is the only change I have made permanent to the configuration and it has solved the issue I was experiencing over several upgrades. Your answer as it stands is not exactly what I have implemented but I am confident it would work too. Thanks again