# Why is NetworkManager included in Ubuntu Server 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager

I am a bit confused about why NetworkManager (and Modem-Manager) are a part of Ubuntu Server 18.04 and why they are enabled services by default.

My understanding is that Netplan is the default tool to be used to configure networking via systemd-networkd.

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04 with Seafile running. Wireless Networking was configured using Netplan and networkd which works fine most of the time. I do have an issue that is described here: [Ubuntu Server Wifi connection fails after each sudo apt upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173502/ubuntu-server-wifi-connection-fails-after-each-sudo-apt-upgrade)

While trying to troubleshoot this issue I found log entries for NetworkManager which could have been errors so I tried disabling it. The server continues to work fine without it but I think the problem in the link above still remains

So why is NetworkManager there and enabled by default? Is there a use case that needs it rather than Netplan? Am I missing some functionality by disabling it?

Comment: Kind of a rant... however... edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo lshw -C network`,

Comment: @heynnema I am very sorry if this came over as a rant. That was not my intention, I just want to understand these things better. I don't appear to have lost anything by disabling NetworkManager other than a few error messages. However I thought it is possible that there may be a downside that I have not discovered. I have added the output you requested to the question referenced above. Thanks for your time in thinking about this.

Comment: Those command outputs should have been here, not some old post from Sept. Anyway, your .yaml files are messed up. You've got two overlapping .yaml files, two similar static IP addresses assigned to two network interfaces, and "optional: true" on the wireless interface.

Comment: For server I always remove NetworkManager, enable systemd-networkd and never have a problem. NM is a bit of a beast but has unfortunately become the default everywhere. I use a simple text config even for my mobile devices and have far fewer problems than I did with NM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a server environment, normally netplan/networkd is used, due mostly to the static nature of its networking environment. NetworkManager is there as a choice, normally not chosen, but should be enabled and left alone.

Have only ONE .yaml file in /etc/netplan. It should look like something similar to this...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  wifis:
    wlp1s0:
      addresses: [192.168.0.66/24] # don't use the same IP address as enp3s0
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      access-points:
        "99PinkGins":
          password: "###############"
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain why NetworkManager should be enabled because the server connects without it? netplan.io seems to be quite clear that its networkd or NetworkManager.

Comment: My yaml file was written with the intention than only one interface would be operational at any one time and that it would always be 192.168.0.66. Normally it runs on wifi and is located in a place where there is no ethernet. Exceptionally I would take it somewhere where there is an ethernet available but the wifi is not. Both wifis and ethernets have optional: true to avoid unnecessary waits while booting. This all seems to work except for the issue linked to updates.

Comment: The .yaml file can specify renderer: as either networkd or NetworkManager. If your ethernet is only connected when elsewhere, then it should be `dhcp4: yes` and not a static IP that you couldn't possibly know would be valid in a foreign network. `Optional: true` is used for wired connections to eliminate a possible 2 minute delays if the cable is not connected, or the network isn't available. On wireless network connections, you need to wait until the connection is completed.

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting. The place with ethernet is a workshop at home on the same home network. I am wondering if removing the optional: true for the wifis might solve my issue related to updates. Thanks again.

Comment: You said "*Exceptionally I would take it somewhere where there is an ethernet available*"... now we learn it's on the same home network... so the .yaml would be different again... sigh. Anyway, try the wireless and report back.

Comment: You really do not need Network Manager. I find life is simpler without it -- even on my laptops.

Comment: @StephenBoston Laptops running Ubuntu Desktop, esp in a wireless environment, should be running with NetworkManager. Just because you may or may not have a specific problem with NM, doesn't mean that netplan is the right fix. In a server environment, NM causes no problem when it's not set as renderer:.

Comment: @heynnema. thanks again for your help today. I have removed the "optional: true" entry from my wificonfig.yaml file and renamed the 50-cloud-init.yaml to 50-cloud-init.yaml.bak so there is only 1 yaml file processed by "sudo netplan --debug generate". I will keep an eye on things over the coming weeks and see if package updates followed by a reboot leads to a network connection or not.

Comment: @PonJar Did you do the last two commands in my answer? Did you re-enable NetworkManager? Are you still using your old .yaml file, or mine? If it all works, please remember to accept my answer at both of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: I definitely will accept your answer to my other question if it proves to solve the problem but since it involves the application of updates and there are currently none to apply then I don’t yet know. I’d say the issue arises on 75% of occasions so I’d like to see it work at least twice on its weekly cycle. I am using two of your suggestions as described in my comment above and have performed the Netplan generate and apply steps. Thanks for your help with the other question, no one had commented on it before you did yesterday, I do appreciate your time

Comment: As things stand I don’t think I can accept your answer in respect of this question. There is clearly a difference in opinion about the need for NetworkManager in this scenario. Disabling it has created no new issues. The heart of this question is “Am I missing some functionality by disabling it?”. This hasn’t really been addressed in your answer but I’d like to understand why in your opinion I should enable it and leave it alone. Thanks again for your time

Comment: @heynnema Why 'should' use NM? What is 'should not' about using networkd and netplan? I am looking for more than a simple assertion of authority.

Comment: @StephenBoston In a server environment, **normally** netplan is used, **mostly** because the environment is mostly static. NM is there **normally** as an option to networkd, but is **usually** not choosen, and having it there causes no problem. In a desktop environment, NM is a better choice, especially because the environment can change frequently, as in hoping from wireless network to wireless network, or plugging into a business network vs home network, you can't have users editing .yaml files just to obtain connection.

Comment: @PonJar In a server environment, using netplan, disabling, or even uninstalling NM, will do no harm. But, if you've chosen networkd as your renderer, having NM sitting there, doing nothing, causes no harm either... so why would you disable it? It's like a car... if you don't use the radio... it causes no harm... so why would you remove/disaable the radio just because you don't use it. It reduces choices.

Comment: @heynnema For a multi-user mobile device where desktop users do not have write access to the /etc/netplan directory, or where users have difficulty editing text files, then I take your point. However in practice I find that creating a connection in NM is more work than adding an entry to the netplan yaml. But I do take your point as applicable for certain users and use cases however I hold back against a globally applicable 'should' for NM.

Comment: @heynnema Turning off one radio when you already have a radio you prefer... Why have two? To be fair though I don't purge NM from my laptops. Sometimes it is useful as a cross check. But I have had fewer intractable network problems since abandoning NM. Different strokes?

Comment: @StephenBoston just curious... if you were using NM, would you be using NM GUI to configure your connections, or editing /etc/network/interfaces?

Comment: When I have used NM I have used the GUI. I have used nmcli in debugging but not in configuration. I haven't used /etc/network/interfaces since 16.10 --  I think it was. I liked netplan right away. And I"m one of those who likes systemd too, so... a heathen to some.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information about the best use cases for Netplan and NM. That makes perfect sense and confirms that I am unlikely to have problems with Netplan and a disabled NM in my use case. I prefer to disable NM if it’s not doing anything other than adding extra lines to the logs. If you would like to copy the essence of your comments today into the answer I’d be happy to mark it as accepted. Thanks again

Comment: @PonJar I did a slight edit to my answer about 8 hours ago. Check it out and vote as you wish. Thanks!